# Drupal website backup without access to FTP server

Tags: drupal

Is it possible in Drupal to make a copy of existing live website via CMS only and download it to my machine and then restore it in the other server? I read about 
backup_migrate module

https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

but will it work for me when I don't have credentials to FTP? Does this feature include in the copy of the website all the resources/images/theme of the website, the css/scripts/icons files etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can get database dump for sure, but I'm not 100% sure about the files, so better try it out.

BTW how can you install backup & migrate if you don't have ftp access?

Also, if you have access to hoster's control panel probably there is an option to download the files.

When making back-up of files you can fine tune what files exactly you want to export. I.e. by default cache files are excluded from backup.